# Поиск одно- и многострочных комментариев в коде только не в строковых литералах

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

```
@"(?x)
( ""
  (?> (?<=@.) (?>[^""]+|"""")*  
    | (?> [^""\\]+ | \\. )* 
  ) 
  ""
| ' (?> [^'\\]+ | \\. )* '
)
| // .* 
| /\* (?s) .*? \*/ ";
```

По сути очищает исходный текст от комментариев типа // и /* */. Выражение работает ,но я не понимаю механику этого выражения
https://regex101.com/r/oIh9lk/2

Comment: По сути очищает исходный текст от комментариев типа // и /* */. Выражение работает ,но я не понимаю механику этого выражения

Comment: Тут как минимум флагов не хватает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, C#? Может `@"` - это тоже часть регулярки?

Comment: *По сути очищает исходный текст от комментариев типа* - регулярное выражение само по себе ничего очищать не может, покажите фрагмент кода, в котором вы его используете

Comment: @АндрейNOP, там внутри кавычки удвоены, так что это код строки на шарпе.

Comment: Простите , что долго не отписывался вот код

Comment: string inLine = inFile.ReadToEnd();
            string pattern;
            pattern = @"(?x)
( ""
  (?> (?<=@.) (?>[^""]+|"""")*  
    | (?> [^""\\]+ | \\. )* 
  ) 
  ""
| ' (?> [^'\\]+ | \\. )* '
)
| // .* 
| /\* (?s) .*? \*/ ";

Comment: Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            string outLine;
            outLine = regex.Replace(inLine, @"$1");
            StreamWriter outFile;
            try
            {outFile = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\output.txt");}
            catch (SecurityException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

Comment: да это c#,  простите за форматирование еще не разобрался

Comment: В вопрос код добавляйте, а не в комментарии

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Регулярные выражения такого рода всегда рекомендуется снабжать комментариями, здесь даже опция `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` уже используется, так почему бы этим режимом не воспользоваться?

```
@"(?x)                           # Включаем режим комментариев
( ""                             # (начало захватыващей подмаски №1) двойная кавычка
  (?> (?<=@.)                    # (Начало атомарной группы) Если это verbatim string literal, 
    (?>[^""]+|"""")*             # 1+ символов, отлчных от ", или "", 0 и более повторов 
    |                            # или (если это обычный строковой литерал) 
    (?> [^""\\]+                 #  1+ символов, отличных от " и \  
      |                          # или
      \\.                        # любой экранированный символ
    )*                           # 0 и более повторов 
  )                              # Конец атомарной группы
  ""                             # Двойная кавычка (конец строкового литерала)
| ' (?> [^'\\]+ | \\. )* '       # или обычный строковой литерал с одинарными кавычками (аналогичный стрововому литералу с двйоными кавычками)
)                                # Конец захватыващей подмаски №1
| // .*                          # Или // и затем 0 и более любых символов кроме переноса строки (однострочный комментарий)
| /\* (?s) .*? \*/               # /*, 0 и более любых знаков (так как (?s) - это RegexOptions.Singleline), как можно меньше, а затем */ (многострочный комментарий)
";
```

Выражение такое длинное, потому что его цель - искать совпадения (одно- и многострочные комментарии) только не в строковых литералах. Чтобы этого избежать, используется обычная для регулярных выражений тактика: ищем то, что нам не нужно, одновременно захватывая этот текст в захватывающую подмаску, находим остальное, что нужно удалить, без захвата, и в шаблоне замены указываем обратную ссылку на значение захватывающей группы (тут только одна, `$1`).

Хотя ленивые квантификаторы в .NET работают неплохо, я бы рекомендовал `/\* (?s) .*? \*/` заменить более эффективным `/\*+[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/` (шаблон взят из книги  "Регулярные выражения" Дж.Фридла, раздел "Удаление комментариев на C").

- `/\*+` - знак `/` и 1 и более знаков `*`
- `[^*]*\*+` - 0+ символов, отличных от `*`, за которыми следует 1 и более знаков `*`
- `(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*` - 0 и более последовательностей (повторов):

  - `[^/*][^*]*\*+` - символ, отличный от `/` и `*`, за которым следует 0 и более символов, отличных от `*`, за которым следует 1 и более знаков `*`
- `/` - знак `/`